# Train with tensorflow 2 on google cloud

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud

How to use tensorflow 2 for training the model on google cloud (ai-platform)?

I see that the only available runtime version is 1.14
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ... --python-version 3.5 --runtime-version 1.14
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719700/tensorflow-2-on-google-cloud-ai-platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get accustomed to using TensorFlow 2, you will first need to create a Deep Learning Virtual Machine [1] and then experiment on some tutorials [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images

[2] https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

[3] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/tensorflow-2-0-and-cloud-ai-make-it-easy-to-train-deploy-and-maintain-scalable-machine-learning-models

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the issue is actually with submitting a training job using `gcloud`, but not creating an instance

Comment: You can configure and submit a training job by running "gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training" from the command line or by sending a request to the API at projects.jobs.create [1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training [2] https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-jobs

Comment: Yes I know, but as you can see from the link in a question, the latest available tf version is 1.14, but not 2

Comment: There has been a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/144390939) submitted regarding this issue and has been reviewed by the Product team. However, there is no ETA at the moment. I recommend to bookmark the link to obtain regular updates and fixes