# Tensorflow 2 on Google Cloud AI platform

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Any news when Tensorflow 2 will be supported on Google Cloud AI platform?

According to the list, 1.15 is the last version to be supported: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list

Comment: You can use custom-containers for Model training if needed. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-containers-training

Answer (score 2):

we will support TF 2.1 officially in early Feb due to large corresponding changes on service. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: any update on this, I'd really like to get started with gpu (or even tpu) training, and atm can install tensorflow 2.1 on ai-platform but only use cpu training

Comment: @MarkEssel down-grade to TF 2.0 to use GPU.

Comment: looks like support began March 9th https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency `tensorflow-gpu==2.0` to `setup.py` file to train  with Tensorflow 2.0 in AI Platform run-time version 1.15. Tensorflow 2.1 can't use GPUs due to mismatch in CUDA libraries, but you can train with CPUs. Be careful that other dependencies don't overwrite `tensorflow-gpu`. Disclaimer: I trained just one job this way, and this is a really hacky solution.

Comment: I'm using the same with  cpu training until  ai-platform supports tensorflow 2.1 with  gpu

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow 2.1** runtime version is available as of March 9th

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list